# Is there a way to query the Portfolio Item Status (Color) in Rally?

Tags: rally

I'd like to use the **custom list app** in Rally to display only those Portfolio Items that have an [At Risk / Red status (see Rally documentation)](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/agile-development-and-management/rally-platform-ca-agile-central/rally/using-top/getting-started-rally-portfolio-manager/track-portfolio-items.html) so I can create a list of items needing attention/for discussion.

e.g. something like `(PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate.Status = "At Risk")`

Is this possible? Or would I need to recreate the colour logic in my query?

Answer (score 0):

I like the concept. Unfortunately, the status color calculation is a bit involved and depends on a lot of different fields. It's not stored as an attribute on the artifact but rather calculated in real time as needed. It would probably be more feasible to load all of the portfolio items first, apply the health color calculations, and then filter by the color hex value before adding the data to a grid.

The status color would be retrieved like so:

```
var colorObject = Rally.util.HealthColorCalculator.calculateHealthColorForPortfolioItemData(recordData, 'PercentDoneByStoryCount') // Or 'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate'
```

The hex value would then be accessed via `colorObject.hex`.

And the hex values used by Rally are:

- Red: #F66349
- Green: #8DC63F
- Yellow: #FAD200
- White: #E0E0E0
- Grey: #D1D1D1